# How to track link clicks for external sites using Google Tag Manager and G4A?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Let's say I have a landing page URL that is not on my own site, `www.notmysite.example/somepage` and I want to advertise this link. I would like to create a URL that is tracked through my G4A Tag Manager, whereby the link click, referrer, etc., are all tracked in a G4A campaign.

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0yereF5nDc) that uses the older Universal Analytics and it's looks like a convoluted solution.

Basically, I just want an intermediary link that tracks the click and redirects to the proper page.

Since I do have access to a WordPress site that has G4A tracking, I'm thinking of creating a redirect on that page that reads the URL parameters.  However I'd rather not have to deal with another system and configure redirects this way.

How can I accomplish this with G4A and Google Tag Manager?

*-- UPDATE --*

I'll try to clarify.  Given a link like a GoFundMe campaign link, GoFundMe has their own internal tracking and analytics.  However, I can't see how to add tracking to that link for my own personal use and/or see analytics on their site.  Therefore, I want to create my own link that does the analytics tracking then forwards the user to the desired page.

Answer (score 1):

In following the video I cited above, I was able to create an intermediary link capture but it does require a page on your website, where you can add a brief "loading" image or something.

This solution involves the following steps:

- `url-redirect_parameter` URL variable, where if the "redirect" query key is present, it will fire

[image]

- Create a `redirect` CUSTOM JavaScript variable that reads the `url-redirect_parameter` variable

  function() {
  try {
  return {{url-redirect_parameter}}?setTimeout(function(){window.location='{{url-redirect_parameter}}'},500):false;
  }
  catch(e) {
  return e;
  }
  }

This custom JS variable references a redirect tag with the following configurations
[image]

- `redirect Trigger` trigger that to your GA tag on your website
  [image]

[image]

What this captures now is whenever there is a "redirect=" in the query string, the trigger will fire, record and redirect.

Another solution is just to add UTM parameters to a page you control on your site and have code on that page to auto-redirect to a QS parameter as well.  This essentially does just that by injecting JS that does the redirect if the QS is present.

I hope his helps someone else looking for a similar solution and open to other solutions, like a G4A solution.

Here is the Universal Analytics result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understand your situation and your goal based on your explation.

But assuming you have back-end access to where you'll be adding the link you wanted to track, you can also track event using [google data layer](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer) instead of redirects

All you have to do is listen to the click event of the button

e.g.

```
<a href="www.notmysite.example/somepage" id="track-me">Click Me</a>
```

event and datalayer

```
const link = document.getElementById('track-me')

link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [] // this should have been already in your script if you are using GA script

    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'click',
        'time': new Date().toLocaleString(),
        'clickFrom': window.location.href,
        'referrer': document.referrer
    })
})
```

Comment: No, that's not quite what I'm looking for.  This is a link that I have no control over other than posting it everywhere.  I want to track the clicks to that link that is not owned by me.